# Key no longer considered "down" after another key is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to make a simple third person camera rotate around my character. I want the X key to rotate right and the Z key to rotate left. I have this working. My issue is, when I have one of the keys pressed and held (say X), then press any other key, `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)` stops returning true. So for the following simple example, it would print the message until another key is pressed, then will not again until I re-press the key.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
    {
        print("X is down"); 
    }
}
```

This prevents me from being able to rotate the camera while moving my character, for as soon as I attempt to change directions via an arrow key, it renders my if statement false. Is there another method I should be using?

Edit - This is not an issue with Unity or my code. I was using Teamviewer, which must handle the inputs differently

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to recreate this with what you have posted.

Comment: Can you add what version of unity you are using?

Comment: @Eddge Goodness, I figured it out. I was remoted into my laptop that was running unity via Teamviewer. That was the problem. It works when used directly from the laptop. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Nick Lol ^^ good to know though ;)

Comment: you should create your own answer and mark it green, this is allowed

Comment: @Fredou, I know it's allowed, it just felt a bit like a non-answer. I will mark mine complete when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being due to remote access. I was using Teamviewer to remote into the laptop that was running Unity. Once I used the laptop directly it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Could it be you are using else if while checking if the button is pressed?

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
    {
        print("X is down");
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Y))
    {
        print("Y is down");
    }
```

It also works for me if i have only 1 if. Even if i press any other key "X is down" is printed.

Comment: The code I posted is my full example. Just the 1 if. If, while holding x, I press and release another key (still holding x), it does not print the message...

Comment: I figured it out. I was remoted into my laptop that was running unity via Teamviewer. That was the problem. It works when used directly from the laptop. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a hardware issue. Different quality levels of keyboards have different behavior. For example, I once had a keyboard where if I pressed more than three keys at the same time, it would not register when they were released, and my character would be stuck running or spinning or whatever until I pressed and released the key again. Expensive "gaming" keyboards should handle multiple simultaneous keypresses better than others. YMMV.